# Splitting Up Integrals and Multiplying Them

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$I_x = \int_0^b\int_0^h\rho y^2\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$

So here's the current problem I'm working on, just for an example. I saw my teacher break up a triple integral in class today then multiply the individual integrals by each other. Is this always legit? How is it done properly? Is what's written below a legitimate way to rewrite my problem? Is there a term to properly describe this?

$$I_x = \rho\int_0^b1\mathrm{d}x\int_0^hy^2\mathrm{d}y$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can break up the multi-variable function into a product of single-variable functions, for example

$$ f(x, y, z) = g(x) \, h(y) \, k(z) $$

and the limits of the variables do not depend on each other, then you can always do this.